# Can an installed PWA create and upload mulitple files from a single user prompt via FileSystemAccessAPI?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, file-system-access-api

I created a desktop app using Adobe/Harman AIR that I would like to recreate from scratch as a PWA.

I'm researching if the PWA would be able to handle all the tasks that the AIR app does.

One of the tasks the AIR app does is iterate through an SQLite database (saved on the user's machine) 5000 rows at a time, take those 5000 rows, perform some formatting on them, save them as a .csv file, upload this .csv file to the server database, then come back and process the next 5000 rows in the SQLite DB and repeat until the whole SQLite DB has been uploaded to the database.

Will the FileSystemAccessAPI allow for a task such as this from a single user prompt, or only simple one-off file uploads?

Thank you